# How to prevent in highlighting the next row in datagridview every time you hit enter key?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying it in C# language.. I don't know how to accomplish it. Please help me guys...

Thanks...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add an event to the `DataGridView` control.

```
private void dataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyData == Keys.Enter)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

This event bypasses the undesired behavior of the `DataGridView` when `Enter` key is being pressed.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the [`SelectionMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectionmode.aspx) to `CellSelect` and it will only select the cell.